# How to download pmd_ruleset file for maven pmd plugin?

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I am trying to add maven pmd plugin in my codebase. added below code in pom file but not sure where to download the pmd_ruleset.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>../pmd_ruleset.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <targetJdk>11</targetJdk>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
                <goal>cpd-check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Actually I tried to download using  http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/index.html but it is not working. Is there any way to download pmd_ruleset.xml file for maven-pmd-plugin artifact version 3.17.0

Reference - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[maven-pmd-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/index.html)'s latest version is [3.17.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/3.17.0). By default, it will use PMD 6.46.0.

When using maven-pmd-plugin, you don't need to provide your own ruleset. As mentioned in [Using Rule Sets](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html):

> The PMD plugin ships a default rule set, that has various rules enabled. The ruleset is available as /rulesets/java/maven-pmd-plugin-default.xml.

If you run `mvn clean verify`, you can see the ruleset in your maven build directory (for me it's `target/pmd/rulesets/maven-pmd-plugin-default.xml`). You can also view it [online](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven-pmd-plugin.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/main/resources/rulesets/java/maven-pmd-plugin-default.xml;hb=HEAD).

If you'd like to use your own ruleset, you can follow PMD's [Making rulesets](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) document and try to make your own ruleset.

It's also possible to download some rulesets online. E.g., you can search PMD rulesets on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Axml%20filename%3Apmd-rule&type=Code).

Comment: wooow. it is easy to see where pmd.xml is located :) thank you much. can we see the for <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>? I could not checkstyle.xml in target folder? do you have any idea?

Comment: I think the maven-checkstyle-plugin will generate a `checkstyle-checker.xml` in the target folder. According to the doc https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html, There are 2 predefined Checkstyle configuration definitions that ship with the Checkstyle Plugin, the Sun Microsystems Definition is selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

The default ruleset file is included with the plugin, so it's possible you don't need the custom ruleset in the first place. However, if you do, there are some options:

- The default ruleset at https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven-pmd-plugin.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/main/resources/rulesets/java/maven-pmd-plugin-default.xml;hb=HEAD
- The plugin's documentation contains examples on how to use custom rule sets : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell how did you get above default ruleset? Is it for 3.17.0 artifactId version ?

Comment: If I understand correct, the plugin iteself use predefined rule set. The reason I want to see and download the xml file is , want to externally add it in eclipse to apply the pmd rules.

Comment: I retrieved the default ruleset from its link at the plugin documentation -- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html

If you need to get the one specifically for 3.17.0, I'm not sure what to tell you -- that version is _old_. The 6.0.0 and later releases changed the rule format.

As a general rule I would recommend adding the plugin to the build rather than to Eclipse directly; however, applying it to Eclipse would be a matter of finding the old 3.17.0 ruleset XML -- which I have not been able to find -- and then saving it locally to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. can you tell how are you telling 3.17.0 is old version. as per the above doc this is the latest version.